# What is the equivalent of Go's range time.Tick?

Tags: concurrency, rust

I'm new to and studying Rust currently, coming from Go. How do I implement something like long concurrent polling?

```go
// StartGettingWeather initialize weather getter and setter
func StartGettingWeather() {

    // start looping
    for i := range time.Tick(time.Second * time.Duration(delay)) {
        _ = i
        loopCounter++
        fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.RFC850), " counter: ", loopCounter)
        mainWeatherGetter()
    }
}
```

and I will call this func as `go StartGettingWeather()`

Comment: there used to be a Timer in std but now it's deprecated. You can take a look at this crate for a replacement: https://github.com/PeterReid/timer . periodic_ms should work more or less like time.Tick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust threads are OS threads, they use OS scheduler and so you can emulate this with `thread::sleep_ms`:

```
use std::thread;

fn start_getting_weather() {
    let mut loop_counter = 0;
    loop {
        loop_counter += 1;
        println!("counter: {}", loop_counter);
        main_weather_getter();
        thread::sleep_ms(delay);
    }
}

thread::spawn(move || start_getting_weather());
```

Comment: hi, thanks for that!, it worked well. I guess ill be using this, thank you again.